# Python Dependency Injection Framework

Tags: python, dependency-injection

Is there a framework equivalent to Guice (http://code.google.com/p/google-guice) for Python?

Answer (score 25):

[Spring Python](http://springpython.webfactional.com) is an offshoot of the Java-based Spring Framework and Spring Security, targeted for Python. This project currently contains the following features:

- [Inversion Of Control (dependency injection)](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) - use either classic XML, or the python @Object decorator (similar to the Spring JavaConfig subproject) to wire things together. While the @Object format isn't identical to the Guice style (centralized wiring vs. wiring information in each class), it is a valuable way to wire your python app.
- [Aspect-oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) - apply interceptors in a horizontal programming paradigm (instead of vertical OOP inheritance) for things like transactions, security, and caching.
- DatabaseTemplate - Reading from the database requires a monotonous cycle of opening cursors, reading rows, and closing cursors, along with exception handlers. With this template class, all you need is the SQL query and row-handling function. Spring Python does the rest.
- Database Transactions - Wrapping multiple database calls with transactions can make your code hard to read. This module provides multiple ways to define transactions without making things complicated.
- Security - Plugin security interceptors to lock down access to your methods, utilizing both authentication and domain authorization.
- Remoting - It is easy to convert your local application into a distributed one. If you have already built your client and server pieces using the IoC container, then going from local to distributed is just a configuration change.
- Samples - to help demonstrate various features of Spring Python, some sample applications have been created:

  - PetClinic - Spring Framework's sample web app has been rebuilt from the ground up using python web containers including: [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/). Go check it out for an example of how to use this framework. (NOTE: Other python web frameworks will be added to this list in the future).
  - Spring Wiki - Wikis are powerful ways to store and manage content, so we created a simple one as a demo!
  - Spring Bot - Use Spring Python to build a tiny bot to manage the IRC channel of your open source project.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that SpringPython does **not** support Python 3, and it haven't seen any activity since 2014...

Answer (score 21):

I like this simple and neat framework.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/injector/

> Dependency injection as a formal pattern is less useful in Python than
>   in other languages, primarily due to its support for keyword
>   arguments, the ease with which objects can be mocked, and its dynamic
>   nature.
>
> That said, a framework for assisting in this process can remove a lot
>   of boiler-plate from larger applications. That's where Injector can
>   help. It automatically and transitively provides keyword arguments
>   with their values. As an added benefit, Injector encourages nicely
>   compartmentalized code through the use of Module s.
>
> While being inspired by Guice, it does not slavishly replicate its
>   API. Providing a Pythonic API trumps faithfulness.

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative to monkeypatching, I like DI. A nascent project such as http://code.google.com/p/snake-guice/ may fit the bill.

Or see the blog post [Dependency Injection in Python](http://web.archive.org/web/20090628142546/http://planet.open4free.org/tag/dependency%20injection/) by Dennis Kempin (Aug '08).

Answer (score 9):

pinject (https://github.com/google/pinject) is a newer alternative. It seems to be maintained by Google and follows a similar pattern to Guice (https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), it's Java counterpart.

Comment: While pinject seems great, it has not been maintained for years, with pull requests adding support for Python 2.6 and 3.x left open for about as long.

Comment: Just FYI that pinject seems active again.

Comment: Now it seems unmaintained again. Last commit was nearly 2 years ago and the github repository shows a warning *"This repository has been archived by the owner on Jan 10, 2023. It is now read-only."*.

Answer (score 5):

Besides that:

1. [Zope component architekture](http://wiki.zope.org/zope3/ComponentArchitectureApproach)
2. [pyContainer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyContainer)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to do dependency injection in Python, you don't need a framework. Have a look at [Dependency Injection the Python Way](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413268-dependency-injection-the-python-way/). It's really quick and easy, and only c. 50 lines of code.

Comment: I did not like this article because the dependencies are not really injected and the classes will depend on the feature locator.

Answer (score 3):

There is a somewhat Guicey [python-inject](https://github.com/ivankorobkov/python-inject) project. It's quite active, and a LOT less code then Spring-python, but then again, I haven't found a reason to use it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Will leave my 5 cents here :)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dependency_injector

```
"""Pythonic way for Dependency Injection."""

from dependency_injector import providers
from dependency_injector import injections


@providers.DelegatedCallable
def get_user_info(user_id):
    """Return user info."""
    raise NotImplementedError()


@providers.Factory
@injections.inject(get_user_info=get_user_info)
class AuthComponent(object):
    """Some authentication component."""

    def __init__(self, get_user_info):
        """Initializer."""
        self.get_user_info = get_user_info

    def authenticate_user(self, token):
        """Authenticate user by token."""
        user_info = self.get_user_info(user_id=token + '1')
        return user_info


print AuthComponent
print get_user_info


@providers.override(get_user_info)
@providers.DelegatedCallable
def get_user_info(user_id):
    """Return user info."""
    return {'user_id': user_id}


print AuthComponent().authenticate_user(token='abc')
# {'user_id': 'abc1'}
```

**UPDATED**

Some time passed and Dependency Injector is a bit different now. It's better to start from Dependency Injector GitHub page for getting actual examples - https://github.com/ets-labs/python-dependency-injector

Comment: I like this answer because you gave code. If I get a chance to try it, I'll give my vote.

Comment: Hi @MikeD, thanks, nice to hear. Code here is a bit outdated, please, go to https://github.com/ets-labs/python-dependency-injector so you could find actual one.

Answer (score 3):

After years using Python without any DI autowiring framework and Java with Spring I've come to realize that plain simple Python code often doesn't need a framework for dependency injection autowiring (autowiring is what Guice and Spring both do in Java), i.e., just doing something like this is enough:

```py
def foo(dep = None):  # great for unit testing!
    ...
```

This is pure dependency injection (quite simple) but without magical frameworks for automatically injecting them for you.

Though as I dealt with bigger applications this approach wasn't cutting it anymore. So I've come up with [injectable](https://github.com/allrod5/injectable) a micro-framework that wouldn't feel non-pythonic and yet would provide first class dependency injection autowiring.

Under the motto *Dependency Injection for Humans™* this is what it looks like:

```py
# some_service.py
class SomeService:
    @autowired
    def __init__(
        self,
        database: Autowired(Database),
        message_brokers: Autowired(List[Broker]),
    ):
        pending = database.retrieve_pending_messages()
        for broker in message_brokers:
            broker.send_pending(pending)
```

```py
# database.py
@injectable
class Database:
    ...
```

```py
# message_broker.py
class MessageBroker(ABC):
    def send_pending(messages):
        ...
```

```py
# kafka_producer.py
@injectable
class KafkaProducer(MessageBroker):
    ...
```

```py
# sqs_producer.py
@injectable
class SQSProducer(MessageBroker):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example for a dependency injection container that does constructor injection based on the constructor argument names:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576609-non-invasive-dependency-injection/

Answer (score 1):

I made a lib to do this
https://github.com/ettoreleandrotognoli/python-cdi
I hope that helps

It's available on pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycdi

With it you can make injections with python2

```
import logging
from logging import Logger

from pycdi import Inject, Singleton, Producer
from pycdi.shortcuts import call


@Producer(str, _context='app_name')
def get_app_name():
    return 'PyCDI'


@Singleton(produce_type=Logger)
@Inject(app_name=str, _context='app_name')
def get_logger(app_name):
    return logging.getLogger(app_name)


@Inject(name=(str, 'app_name'), logger=Logger)
def main(name, logger):
    logger.info('I\'m starting...')
    print('Hello World!!!\nI\'m a example of %s' % name)
    logger.debug('I\'m finishing...')


call(main)
```

And using type hints from python3

```
import logging
from logging import Logger

from pycdi import Inject, Singleton, Producer
from pycdi.shortcuts import call


@Producer(_context='app_name')
def get_app_name() -> str:
    return 'PyCDI'


@Singleton()
@Inject(logger_name='app_name')
def get_logger(logger_name: str) -> Logger:
    return logging.getLogger(logger_name)


@Inject(name='app_name')
def main(name: str, logger: Logger):
    logger.info('I\'m starting...')
    print('Hello World!!!\nI\'m a example of %s' % name)
    logger.debug('I\'m finishing...')


call(main)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17853169)

Comment: I have put some examples , is better now?

Comment: the answer in its form is definitely better now. As for the content - I cannot say :)

Comment: Ok, thanks!
So you only check if the answer follow a pattern not the content?

Comment: I saw your answer through special moreration section on this site. There are guidlines as to how to write a good answer regardless of the content - you can find them here on SO. 

When you post just a link - it is not considered to be a good answer. You may post links but they should be accompanied by your own thoughts, comments, code etc.

Comment: I'm only trying to understand the system, the question was very specific  "Is there a framework equivalent to Guice (http://code.google.com/p/google-guice) for Python?" a simple yes could answer that.
But I answer "I made somethint to do that <<link>>" and it is not good enought.
Whereas a answer like this " I like this simple and neat framework. <<link>>" receives 13 votes.
But nevermind, I wont lose more of my time with this.

Comment: Aside from bad answers bad questions exist as well. Also you shouldn't take this word - "bad" - literally and personally. "Bad" answer/question in this context mostly refers to formatting, grammar and logical structure, not the content itself. The question you cited is a bad one.

Comment: Just read the faqs to get a feeling for how a good answer/question should look. There are tons of bad answers/questions on here. Some of them are pretty old and they are treated as legacy. They are closed, but not deleted because they generate some traffic (sometimes significant traffic) for the site. Others are still displayed because the algorithm has't discovered them yet. The SO managers as of now don't want to turn SO into a link farm. You have all the tools to give meaninful answers here. Besides, the links are not prohibited as such - just give a little more than a link.

Answer (score 1):

[Enterprython](https://github.com/Dobiasd/enterprython) is a small framework providing dependency-injection, building the object graph automatically based on [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good comparison (19 September 2020):
[Comparison of Dependency Injection Libraries in Python, and my favorite one](https://wasinski.dev/comparison-of-dependency-injection-libraries-in-python/)

His winners are:

1. [proofit404/dependencies (Injector)](https://github.com/proofit404/dependencies) "simple, but provided all the necessary features. If you need something that’s not provided then just think about the design in your application, cause the flow might be somewhere there. Beautiful configuration. Perfect match for agile projects"
2. [ets-labs/python-dependency-injector](http://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/introduction/di_in_python.html) "very expanded library, with constant support, the problem is it’s boilerplate, if that does not bother you, then it’s a great choice"

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a really tiny solution there's a little function, it is just a dependency setter.

https://github.com/liuggio/Ultra-Lightweight-Dependency-Injector-Python

Comment: This is not more convenient than instantiating the objects directly. Dependency injection does not require a framework.

Answer (score 0):

There's dyject (http://dyject.com), a lightweight framework for both Python 2 and Python 3 that uses the built-in ConfigParser

Answer (score 0):

If you want a guice like (the new new like they say), I recently made something close in Python 3 that best suited my simple needs for a side project.

All you need is an **@inject** on a method (__init__ included of course).
The rest is done through annotations.

```
from py3njection import inject
from some_package import ClassToInject

class Demo:
    @inject
    def __init__(self, object_to_use: ClassToInject):
        self.dependency = object_to_use

demo = Demo()
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py3njection

Answer (score 0):

I recently released a neat (IMHO) micro library for DI in python:

https://github.com/suned/serum

Answer (score 0):

I'm actively developing [pinject](https://github.com/davidcim/wirinj) for Python >= `3.6`. It's quite easy to use:

```
class MyObject:
    my_service: MyService = INJECTED
    my_config: str = INJECTED
```