# More pythonic way of referencing an object's attributes before it is completely initialized

Tags: python

I've encountered a problem where, during the initialization of my main class, I create an instance of another class and attach it to an attribute:

```
# DOES NOT WORK (game instance not initialised yet)
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.radius = game.object_one.width / 2

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.object_one = Foo()
        self.object_two = Bar()

game = Game()
```

I was able to overcome this by simply passing the instance as a parameter:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.radius = obj.width / 2


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.object_one = Foo()
        self.object_two = Bar(self.object_one)

game = Game()
```

This seems quite a band-aid solution for a seemingly simple problem.  Is there a nicer way of doing this? Or is this entire problem a result of bad code? How can it be avoided in the future?

Comment: It is not a band-aid solution, it's called dependency injection, a very common pattern. There are some frameworks that can help you make it nicer, but overall, it's not a bad solution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: Glad to know it's not a bad solution. Never heard of dependency injection before but I think I've ran into it before a few times. Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for though.

Comment: Great, I've also added it as an answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code snippet is not a band-aid solution, it is actually a very common pattern called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Frameworks have been developed to make it nicer (mainly shorter), but overall, it's not a bad solution without the usage of any of these frameworks either. One example of such a framework is [Dependency Injector](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/), but there are [several alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156230/python-dependency-injection-framework).